# Fieldset Not displaying inline

Tags: css, forms, inline, fieldset

I have a form with a birthday fieldset and I've tried multiple tags to force the fields to align in the same row. I have tried display: inline-block; inline; and block with no luck. Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

this is my fieldset:

```
<fieldset class="birthday">
                 <label>Birthday</label>
                  <label class="month"> 
                  <select class="select-style" name="BirthMonth">
                  <option value="">Month</option>
                  <option  value="01">January</option>
                  <option value="02">February</option>
                  <option value="03" >March</option>
                  <option value="04">April</option>
                  <option value="05">May</option>
                  <option value="06">June</option>
                  <option value="07">July</option>
                  <option value="08">August</option>
                  <option value="09">September</option>
                  <option value="10">October</option>
                  <option value="11">November</option>
                  <option value="12" >December</option>
                  </label>
                 </select>    
                <label>Day<input class="birthday" maxlength="2" name="BirthDay"  placeholder="Day" required=""></label>
                <label>Year <input class="birthyear" maxlength="4" name="BirthYear" placeholder="Year" required=""></label>
              </fieldset>
```

this is my css:

```
    .quoteform2 fieldset.birthday {display: inline-block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
    .quoteform2 label.month {width: 135px;}
.quoteform2 .select-style {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-image: url(images/select-arrow.png), 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0px solid #FFF;
  color: #555;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: would be good if you added a fiddle over here .....

Comment: Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yJkL/ - seems to be working fine?

Comment: Also, your `</label>` and `</select>` tags are the wrong way around.

Comment: Do you have some sort of external library as from the code and css you have provided that should all be in the same row

Comment: Pete I'm not sure that I understand your question

Comment: Kai, did you fix the '</label>' and '</select>' in the Fiddle?

Comment: @user3585770 are you using something like twitter bootstrap or other such ui framework

Comment: this form is inserted into a wordpress text module.